# getting a nfsmount error when PXE booting

Tags: boot, networking, mount, nfs, pxe

i'm getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYwJE.png) right here when i'm trying to pxe boot to Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 . I followed this http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13243 guide on how to set it up. The regular command line installation works but I want the desktop installation to work as well, that's the part where i'm running into this "nfsmount: need a path" error. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello,

To fix your issue, you have two options....

**Option 1 - Mount the Ubuntu Desktop cdrom/iso within your PXE server**

As crazy it might sounds,  making the cdrom available on the pxe server will prevent the nfsmount error... If you look in the txt.cfg config file, you will see that in the append line, there is a element file=/cdrom/......  This is causing the issue

**Option 2 -  Update your txt.cfg file  using the following information**

Replace this section (and **update your ip accordingly!!**!)

```
label ubuntudesktop
   menu label Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 Live   
   kernel casper/vmlinuz    
   append nfsroot=192.168.1.150:/var/www/html/desktop/bionic netboot=nfs ro
   file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz
   systemd.mask=tmp.mount --
```

with

```
label ubuntudesktop
   menu label Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 Live
   kernel casper/vmlinuz
   append nfsroot = 192.168.1.193:/var/www/html/desktop/bionic netboot=nfs ro
   boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd systemd.mask=tmp.mount --
```

In the second option, we have simply removed the element file=/cdrom/xxxxxx

Hope this help

Till next time

See ya